To read information from sub directories in blob Azure
I would like to get files stored inside sub directories in the blob . I tried the below code it looks for looks for all sub directories. Please let me know what has be done to look at specific sub directories.
     var blobStorage = new BlobStorage<Documents>(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorage"), "documents");
    
     var itemCount = 0;
     var maxItems = (31 * 100);
   // Sub directories info 2024/Data/
     await foreach (var data in blobStorage.GetBlobs())
     {    
    
        // Get info here
    
         itemCount++;
     }



I tried the below code it looks for looks for all sub directories. Please let me know what has be done to look at specific sub directories.

To list the blobs from specific directory, you can use the prefix parameter that filters the results to return only blobs whose name begins with the specified prefix.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;

namespace ListBlobsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Azure Storage Connection String";
            string containerName = "test";

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            // List blobs in the "2024/Data" subdirectory
            string prefix = "sample/venkat1"; //eg:my subdirectory
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: prefix))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
sample/venkat1/demo.txt
sample/venkat1/file.csv
sample/venkat1/sample.pdf
sample/venkat1/sample.wav
sample/venkat1/samplecert.pfx
sample/venkat1/temp2.jpg
sample/venkat1/test.jpg

Reference:
BlobContainerClient.GetBlobs Method (Azure.Storage.Blobs) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn
